# How to keep nodes on AR Kit Scene after opening UIImagePicker

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I bumped into a problem when all my previously added nodes(for example) text disappearing after opening Photo Library or Camera to add new photo-node. Is there any way to fix it? 
My alerts code:

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Add Text", style: .default , handler:{ (UIAlertAction) in
        self.addTextView.isHidden = false
        self.inputTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
    }))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Choose from Library", style: .default , handler:{ (UIAlertAction) in
        alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        let picker = UIImagePickerController ()
        picker.delegate = self
        picker.allowsEditing = true
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
        self.present (picker, animated: true , completion: nil)
    }))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Take a Photo", style: .default , handler:{ (UIAlertAction) in
        alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        let picker = UIImagePickerController ()
        picker.delegate = self
        picker.allowsEditing = true
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
        self.present (picker, animated: true , completion: nil)
    }))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler:{ (UIAlertAction) in
        // ACTION
    }))

    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem isn't with your alert, but the fact that you are presenting another view - leaving the AR scene.

This is ok, but when you return to the view, your AR scene is likely being reloaded, likely by something called in viewWillAppear or something similar.

Check that, if this is not it, please post code from your lifecycle overrides (viewDidLoad, viewDidAppear, viewWillAppear) - because presenting an alert isn't going to cause this error.

Comment: Thanks. I removed session restore from didAppear() and inserted it only in viewDidLoad(). This killed my "Take Photo" because session cannot get position after camera session.